# Javascript HTML 5 Progress Bar not working with setInterval

Tags: javascript

1. The progress bar increases by 1 when I click the button. But I don't see it increasing to 100. I have to click the button again and again to increase the value. Could you please tell me what I might be doing incorrectly?
2. Also, how do I clear the interval for each individual progress bar once it reaches 100 without using progress bar id?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Hello");
  var button = document.getElementById("animateButton");
  button.onclick = goProgress;
}

function goProgress() {
 console.log("In goProgress()");
  var progressBars = document.getElementsByClassName("progress");
  for(var i=0;i<progressBars.length;i++){
    console.log("Progress Bar " + (i+1) + ": " + progressBars[i]);
    setInterval(increaseVal(progressBars[i]),10);
  }
};

function increaseVal(progressBar){
  console.log("In increaseVal(): " + progressBar.value);
 if(progressBar.value<100){
   progressBar.value = progressBar.value + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<progress class="progress" value="20" max="100"></progress>
<br>
<progress class="progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<br>
<progress class="progress" value="30" max="100"></progress>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Animate" id="animateButton"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setInterval` takes a function as first parameter, you're actually calling the function, you have to only pass the reference.

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) any parameters after the delay will be passed to the function.

```
setInterval(increaseVal, 10, progressBars[i]);
```

To clear the interval once it reaches 100 you will have save the intervalId, the easiest would probably be just writing it to the progressbar.

```
progressBars[i].interval = setInterval(increaseVal, 10, progressBars[i]); 

// snip

function increaseVal(progressBar){
    console.log("In increaseVal(): " + progressBar.value);
    if (progressBar.value < 100) {
        progressBar.value = progressBar.value + 1;
    } else {
        clearInterval(progressBar.interval);
    }
}
```

You could obviously also save them in a custom array but then you will have to pass the array index to the function.

Check the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3crb7dkg/)

Comment: thanks @PostCrafter. what about the second question? how do i clear the interval?

Answer (score 2):

With `setInterval()` you can pass the parameters to the function you want to repeatedly call as the arguments after the delay. Then you can use an array to hold the clearInterval handles for each element with `clr[i] = setInterval(increaseVal, 10, progressBars[i],i);`:

Example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Hello");
  var button = document.getElementById("animateButton");
  button.onclick = goProgress;
}
var clr = [];
function goProgress() {
  console.log("In goProgress()");
  var progressBars = document.getElementsByClassName("progress");
  for (var i = 0; i < progressBars.length; i++) {
    console.log("Progress Bar " + (i + 1) + ": " + progressBars[i]);
    clr[i] = setInterval(increaseVal, 10, progressBars[i],i);
  }
};
function increaseVal(progressBar,i) {
  console.log("In increaseVal() " + i + ": " + progressBar.value);
  if (progressBar.value < 100) {
    progressBar.value = progressBar.value + 1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(clr[i])
  }
}
```

```html
<progress class="progress" value="20" max="100"></progress>
<br>
<progress class="progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<br>
<progress class="progress" value="30" max="100"></progress>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Animate" id="animateButton" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a `function` in the place where you need to pass it as a `reference`. So pass the reference of `increaseVal` function by binding its parameter.

```
for (var i = 0; i < progressBars.length; i++) {
    setInterval(increaseVal.bind(null, progressBars[i]), 10);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3tbbgmsx/1/)

Full code for clearing the `interval`. You can use `dataset` of the progress bar element to accomplish your tasks easily. There is no need to introduce any new variables to your code.

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Hello");
  var button = document.getElementById("animateButton");
  button.onclick = goProgress;

  function goProgress() {
    console.log("In goProgress()");
    var progressBars = document.getElementsByClassName("progress");
    for (var i = 0; i < progressBars.length; i++) {
      progressBars[i].dataset.interval = setInterval(increaseVal.bind(null, progressBars[i]), 10);
    }
  };

  function increaseVal(progressBar) {
    if (progressBar.value < 100) {
      progressBar.value = progressBar.value + 1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(progressBar.dataset.interval);
      console.log(progressBar, "cleared!!");
    }
  }
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3tbbgmsx/3/)

Comment: thanks @rajaprabhu. what about the second question? how do i clear the interval?

Comment: @takeradi Can you try out the new demo? Fixed it.